# Bring application to foreground in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-foreground

Im working in a ios application. when my application is in background, i need to wake it up without user interaction. Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Skype becomes active (foreground) when a voice or video call comes. Similar way i'm asking.

Comment: We can suspend our app by calling      UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];          Is there any way like this to resume our app?

Comment: It is not possible on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *Configuring a Background Update Notification*

form apple documents

> Background update notifications improve the user experience by giving
>   you a way to wake up your app periodically so that it can refresh its
>   data in the background. When apps do not run for extended periods of
>   time, their data can become outdated. When the user finally launches
>   the app again, the outdated data must be replaced, which can cause a
>   delay in using the app. A background update notification can alert the
>   user or it can occur silently.

You can read more there [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

Comment: Thanks, i'm using APN. but i did not no where is payload. i didn't configured it. And my app doesnot call didReceiveRemoteNotification. What was my problem?

Comment: Read document content- available have to be 1 also . In apn dic, Enable remote notification in app back ground mode

Comment: Yes. Enabled remote notification in background. But i don't know where content-available is in my xcode. Can u please explain this?

Comment: This remote notification sent from your server

Comment: Thanks, But my code is not hitting didReceiveRemoteNotificaton.

Comment: Should i export certificate for Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificates in my developer account?

Comment: you just export .p12 file from your key chain  to your backend developer check this link to know how to send .p12 step by step https://www.mobiloud.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-export-push-notification-certificate-p12/

Comment: Thanks. Abdelahad Darwish.

Comment: you always welcome

Comment: hello. I have downloaded .p12 file. And i don't know where to use it. Please tell me where to set content-available key with a value of 1.  Thanks

Comment: you have to send it to backend developer and he will sent in  content-available  please  read this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html